# Use the type's root name when serializing collection items

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Just a contrived example but I have some classes that I want to control the names of when serialized.

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class ItemWrapper
{
    [XmlArray("parts")]
    public List<PartWrapper> Parts { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("part")]
public class PartWrapper
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I serialize an `ItemWrapper` that has some `Parts`, I was expecting each of the `PartWrapper` items to be serialized using the root name (`"part"`) but it instead uses the type's name (what it would use by default if the `XmlRootAttribute` wasn't specified).

```
<item>
  <parts>
    <PartWrapper name="foo" />
    <PartWrapper name="bar" />
  </parts>
</item>
```

Now I know to fix this to get what I want is to add the `XmlArrayItemAttribute` to the `Parts` property to specify the name of each of the items but I feel it's redundant.  I just wanted to use the name of the type's root as I specified.

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlArray("parts")]
    [XmlArrayItem("part", Type=typeof(PartWrapper))]
    public List<PartWrapper> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

**Is there a way that I can tell the serializer that I want to use the root name for the collection items?  If so, how?**

**Why wouldn't it just use the root name?  Any good reason why it shouldn't?**

It was my understanding that the `XmlRootAttribute` allowed you to name the element exactly like an `XmlElementAttribute` does, only it had to be applied to the class.  I guess I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, it seems that `XmlRootAttribute` is used only when that element is the root (which is why it works for "item" in your case):

> Controls XML serialization of the attribute target as an XML root element

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It seems to me like perhaps you want [`XmlTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for things that are not root.

Comment: Ah, so I should have been using `XmlType` all along in the first place. For the longest time, I thought it only associated it with an XSD data type or something. I didn't know what actually set the names on the type correctly, I always thought `XmlRootAttribute` was the only way.